# Git log without cloning the repository?

Tags: git, version-control

git log give us a really good functionality to know about what happened in the project. When we are in our machine and we have the cloned project is just executing the command. But I've realized that sometimes I need to read the log from somewhere else that is not my machine, so it would be great to ask for a log without having the repository cloned.

I've been looking around through google an reading the git-log man page but I didn't found a way to do it.

Does anybody know if this way of log can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if a built-in way for this exists, but you can always fall back to a remote command over ssh:

```
ssh some-host "cd my/repo && git log"
```

This of course only works if you have shell access to the host.